# Delphi change color of main menu

Tags: delphi, menu

I am creating my own OnAdvancedDrawItem to change the color of the MainMenu.  It works well but I get an annoying white line at the bottom.

[image: line under main menu]

It disappears when running the mouse over the menu but comes back when another application is selected.  How can I get rid of it?

Here is my basic code for the background coloring.

```
unit MenMain;

interface

uses Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,Dialogs, Menus, ImgList, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  MainMenu1: TMainMenu;
  File2: TMenuItem;
  Edit1: TMenuItem;
  Window1: TMenuItem;
  procedure Window1AdvancedDrawItem(Sender: TObject; ACanvas: TCanvas; ARect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
private

public

end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Window1AdvancedDrawItem(Sender: TObject; ACanvas: TCanvas;  ARect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
  with TMenuItem(Sender) do
  begin
    with ACanvas do
    begin
      Brush.Color := clMoneyGreen;
      Inc(ARect.Bottom,1);
      FillRect(ARect);
      Font.Color := clBlue;
      DrawText(ACanvas.Handle, PChar(Caption),Length(Caption),ARect,          DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER);
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: That seems to prove what 'ARect' is for, to specify the area that you can draw. What you draw outside may get overdrawn later. The bottom line is probably NC area outside of item area.

Comment: May I ask why you don't use `TMainActionMenuBar`? You can connect it to `TStandardColorMap` and achieve effect that you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ARect` parameter of the `OnAdvancedDrawItem` event handler is the `rcItem` of the `DRAWITEMSTRUCT` that's passed to the `WM_DRAWITEM` message. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has this to say about the rectangle:

> A rectangle that defines the boundaries of the control to be drawn.
>   This rectangle is in the device context specified by the **hDC** member.
>   The system automatically clips anything that the owner window draws in
>   the device context for combo boxes, list boxes, and buttons, but does
>   not clip menu items. When drawing menu items, the owner window must
>   not draw outside the boundaries of the rectangle defined by the **rcItem**
>   member.

So although the device context is not clipped to the rectangle, you're responsible for not drawing outside of it. That happens when you execute `Inc(ARect.Bottom,1);` before filling the rectangle.

Comment: Your answer is very instructive.  However it still leaves me with the problem of preventing windows painting the white line under the menu bar when a repaint is initiated by other than menu actions.

Comment: @Rudi - Well, the answer essentially implied "you cannot get rid of it". Not easily at least. You will not be able to achieve it with owner drawn menus. You have to assume non client area painting yourself. This, I feel, is a complicated subject that falls outside the scope of this question. I certainly do not recommend it either. As you've seen yourself, the OS intervenes with NC painting at pretty weird times, like window deactivation.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of the grey area. Use this in OnCreate and OnCanResize

```
global var - fMenuBrushHandle: THandle;

var
  lMenuInfo: TMenuInfo;
  lMenuColor: TColor;
begin
  lMenuColor := clRed;

  DeleteObject(fMenuBrushHandle);
  fMenuBrushHandle := CreateSolidBrush(ColorToRGB(lMenuColor));

  FillChar(lMenuInfo, SizeOf(lMenuInfo), 0);

  lMenuInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(lMenuInfo);
  lMenuInfo.hbrBack := fMenuBrushHandle;
  lMenuInfo.fMask := MIM_BACKGROUND;
  SetMenuInfo(MainMenu1.Handle, lMenuInfo);
end;
```

or

```
global var - FBrush: TBrush;

var
  lMenuInfo: TMenuInfo;
begin
  if not Assigned(FBrush) then
     FBrush := TBrush.Create;
  FBrush.Color := clRed;
  FBrush.Style := bsSolid;

  lMenuInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(lMenuInfo);
  lMenuInfo.fMask := MIM_BACKGROUND;
  lMenuInfo.hbrBack := FBrush.Handle;
  SetMenuInfo(MainMenu1.Handle, lMenuInfo);
end;
```

or even draw bitmap

```
global var
  fMenuHandle:THandle;
  fBitmap:Tbitmap;

var
  lMenuInfo:TMenuInfo;
begin
  if Assigned(fBitmap) then
    fBitmap.Free;
  fBitmap:=TBitmap.Create;
  fBitmap.Width:=21;
  fBitmap.Height:=Form1.Width;

  DeleteObject(fMenuHandle);
  fMenuHandle:=CreatePatternBrush(fBitmap.Handle);
  Fillchar(lMenuInfo,SizeOf(lMenuInfo),0);

  lMenuInfo.cbSize:=SizeOf(lMenuInfo);
  lMenuInfo.fMask:=MIM_BACKGROUND;
  lMenuInfo.hbrBack:=fMenuHandle;
  SetMenuInfo(MainMenu1.Handle,lMenuInfo);
end;
```